# Angular upload an image to api return empty payload

Tags: angular

I face an issue i try to upload an image to api and it fail.. when i look at my network tab at inspect element, the payload is empty..  here is my function

```
 file:any = [];
 onFileChanged(event) {
    this.file = event.target.files[0];
  }
```

here is my function to send image to api

```
getfinishpic(id?: any) {
    let job_id = id;
    let finish_picture = this.file;
    this.sprayerEarning.finishspraypicture(job_id, finish_picture).subscribe();
  }
```

here how i create post api

```
 finishspraypicture(job_id: string, finish_picture: any) {
    return this.http.post(environment.baseUri+ 'api/earning/spayer-finish', {
      job_id,
      finish_picture,
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to upload using multipart form data. And you need to subscribe the api observable in order to execute the request actually.

```
finishspraypicture(job_id: string, finish_picture: any) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("job_id", job_id);
  formData.append("finish_picture", finish_picture);

  return this.http.post(environment.baseUri + 'api/earning/spayer-finish', formData).subscribe(res => {
    # deal with the response
  });
}
```